# Docketed New Case - Ready for Examination

Tags: patent-applications

What does "Docketed New Case - Ready for Examination" mean? My utility patent application has been given this status. What does that mean and what should I expect next?

Answer (score 4):

This means that your utility patent application has been assigned to an examiner, placed in their docket and that an Office Action will be forthcoming.   If you know the technology center where your application has been assigned, you can go to this link and determine approximately when you will receive an Office Action.   http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/com/sol/og/2015/week03/TOC.htm#ref16